What does Bhagavatham Say about Narasimha Avatharam?
Was his Avatharam only for killing Hiranyakashipu and saving Prahladha or is there any other reason?

As per Bhagavatam, Krishna took avatar to kill Hiranyakadshipu just like other scriptures.

एवं दुरुक्तैर्मुहुरर्दयन् रुषा सुतं महाभागवतं महासुर: । खड्‌गं
प्रगृह्योत्पतितो वरासनात् स्तम्भं तताडातिबल: स्वमुष्टिना ॥ 7.8.14
Being obsessed with anger, Hiraṇyakaśipu, who was very great in bodily
strength, thus chastised his exalted devotee-son Prahlāda with harsh
words. Cursing him again and again, Hiraṇyakaśipu took up his sword,
got up from his royal throne, and with great anger struck his fist
against the column.
तदैव तस्मिन्निनदोऽतिभीषणो बभूव येनाण्डकटाहमस्फुटत् । यं वै
स्वधिष्ण्योपगतं त्वजादय: श्रुत्वा स्वधामात्ययमङ्ग मेनिरे ॥ 7.8.15
Then from within the pillar came a fearful sound, which appeared to
crack the covering of the universe. O my dear Yudhiṣṭhira, this sound
reached even the abodes of the demigods like Lord Brahmā, and when the
demigods heard it, they thought, “Oh, now our planets are being
destroyed!”
विष्वक्स्फुरन्तं ग्रहणातुरं हरि- र्व्यालो यथाखुं कुलिशाक्षतत्वचम् ।
7.8.29A
As a snake captures a mouse or Garuḍa captures a very venomous snake,
Lord Nṛsiṁhadeva captured Hiraṇyakaśipu, who could not be pierced even
by the thunderbolt of King Indra. ..
निशाम्य लोकत्रयमस्तकज्वरं तमादिदैत्यं हरिणा हतं मृधे ।
प्रहर्षवेगोत्कलितानना मुहु: प्रसूनवर्षैर्ववृषु: सुरस्त्रिय: ॥ 7.8.35
Hiraṇyakaśipu had been exactly like a fever of meningitis in the head
of the three worlds. Thus when the wives of the demigods in the
heavenly planets saw that the great demon had been killed by the
personal hands of the Supreme Personality of Godhead, their faces
blossomed in great joy. The wives of the demigods again and again
showered flowers from heaven upon Lord Nṛsiṁhadeva like rain.


Narasimha is an Avatara of Vishnu. @cracklingcyclone

@SK as per bhagavatam it is Krishna's incarnation isn't it?

@SK he  is using words like demigod. obviously he is using iskcons translation.

Does Bhagavatham contain anymore instances of Narasimha Avatharam?
